# float to right using angular material

Tags: html, css, user-interface, angular-material

I have a md-card-content. Inside it i have a div and a md-card-content. 
The contents of md-card-content(inner) i want to shift to the right. 
I used `padding-left= 50%` but it goes out of page if text in first div is lengthier. 
I also used 
`layout-align="end start"` but it is not working.

```
  <md-card>
  <md-card-content layout="row">       
         <div layout="column">
            <div>
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="extraIcons:offline" class="md-24"></md-icon>
             <span class="md-subhead">{{vm.device.serialNumber}}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
             <md-icon md-svg-icon="extraIcons:offline" class="md-24"></md-icon>
            <span class="md-subhead">{{vm.device.ipAddress}}</span>  
            </div>         
         </div>

         <md-card-content class="layout-row layout-align-end-start">
             <div>
                <md-icon md-svg-icon="extraIcons:{{vm.device.connectionStatus|lowercase}}" class="md-24 "></md-icon>
             </div>
             <div>
                 <md-icon md-svg-icon="extraIcons:{{vm.device.operationalStatus|lowercase}}" class="md-24 {{vm.device.operationalStatus|lowercase}} "></md-icon>
             </div>
    <!--
    <div>
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="extraIcons:{{vm.device.overallStatus|lowercase}}" class="md-24 {{vm.device.overallStatus|lowercase}} "></md-icon>
    </div>
    -->
              <div ng-if="vm.device.requiresMaintenance">
                 <md-icon md-svg-icon="extraIcons:maintenance" class="md-24 maintenance"></md-icon>
              </div>
         </md-card-content>
      </md-card-content>
      </md-card>
```

Comment: so just to be sure, have you seen and tried playing with this values as on this page ? https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment  there is a little demo on the bottom - try it out

Comment: @Marko Yes i played with it and used  <md-card-content layout="row" layout-align="end start"> used it in my code bit it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no point on using md-card-content outside and md-card directive... You're probably getting some styles as a side effect of using these directives in such an incorrect manner.

```
<md-card>
    <md-card-header></md-card-header>
    <md-card-title></md-card-title>
    <md-card-content></md-card-content>
    <md-card-footer></md-card-footer>
    <md-card-actions></md-card-actions>
</md-card>
```

Although the inner parts are optional, the outer md-card is required.

NOTE: You may also consider using classes for the layout attributes, as it's the preferred form since some months ago (I don't remember exactly on which version this was advised on the changelog). So use this:

```
<tag class="layout-row layout-align-end-start" ...>
```

instead of this:

```
<tag layout="row" layout-align="end-start" ...>
```

it will save you from some headaches...

Comment: I have a md-card inside another..Is it due to this i cant get desired op despite using lass="layout-row layout-align-end-start"

Comment: @sameer You've updated the question but your code still shows a md-card-contend nested inside of another, without it's correspondent md-card parent...

Comment: I got my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Since Angular Material uses [Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki), [fxFlex](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API) works really well with mat-card, even multi-level nested cards and remains responsive

```
<div>
  <div id="leftContainer" fxFlex="80%">
    <!-- content goes here -->
  </div>
  <div id="rightContainer" fxFlex="20%">
    <!-- content goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `style="float:right"` and adjust their width like `width:50%`

Answer (score 1):

Working example without any extra custom style

- fxLayoutAlign="flex-end" : Align the content of the div to right
- class="mt10 pl10 pr10" : Give some padding to top, left and right (optional)

```html
  <div class="mt10 pl10 pr10" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign="flex-end">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-placeholder>Search</mat-placeholder>
      <input matInput type="search" [(ngModel)]="searchValue">
      <button mat-icon-button matSuffix color="primary" aria-label="search" (click)="applyFilter($event)">
        <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" [routerLink]="['/users/add']">
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" [routerLink]="['/users/upload']">
      <mat-icon>publish</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
```

[image]